# Page Redirect in Visualforce page - not working

Tags: visualforce, environment

I have visualforce page which opens up using window.open in javascript written behind a custom button.
There is a cancel (apex:commandbutton) on VF page which calls a redirect method.

```
public PageReference redirectToAnother() {
    PageReference pageRef;
    pageRef= new PageReference('/apex/TestPage?param1=ADD+param2=MULTI');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
 }
```

This works perfectly in 3 different sandboxes but doesn't work in 4th one.

- There are no errors being shown in Javascript console in Chrome.
- Firebug also doesn't show any issues.
- The debug logs in salesforce show exactly same statements in all sandboxes.
- In the sandbox whereissue exists, the method is returning the correct url but simply the redirection doesn't happen. It shows a blank screen with the
  currentpage url and all querystring parameters removed.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: TestPage exists and is visible to the context user in the forth sandbox right ? There are no manual setup steps in 4th sandbox that you may have missed ?

Comment: I would instantiate the `PageReference` with `Page.TestPage` instead. You can retrieve the parameters and add to them with `getParameters`. It might not give you more information but it is cleaner imo.

Comment: @CloudHugger yes page permissions exist. no manual setup steps missed.